# Why is select option not displayed in select input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with `react.js`, the problem is there that I have a `select` input field, I get data from `Api` and set to it's `option`, but when I want to select the `second option` or anything else, it does not select, just selects the first one. When I send data to the server it does not have any value. It is empty.

**Here is my select.jsx:**

```
import React from "react";
   const Select = ({ name, label, options, error, ...rest }) => {
   return (
       <div className="form-group">
       <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
           <select name={name} id={name} {...rest} className="form-control">
               {options.map(option => (
               <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
               {option.name}
               </option>
              ))}
           </select>
       {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Select;
```

**This is renderSelect function:**

```
 renderSelect(name, label, options) {
    const { data, errors } = this.state;
    console.log(data[name]);
    return (

        <Select
            name={name}
            value={data[name]} 
            label={label}
            options={options}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            error={errors[name]}
        />
    );
}
```

**This is the state and API:**

```
state = {
data:{name:'',username:'',email:'',role:'',password:''},
roles:[],
errors:{}
};
async componentDidMount() {
   const { data: role } = await axios.get(config.apiEndpont + '/getRole');
   this.setState({ roles: role.roles });

}
```

**This is handleChange:**

```
handelChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(input);
    if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage;
    else delete errors[input.name];
    
    const data = { ...this.state.data };
   
    data[input.name] = input.value;
    this.setState({ data, errors });
}
```

**And this is the form:**

```
return (
  <div>
    <h4>Create New User</h4>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      {this.renderInput("name","Name")}
      {this.renderInput('username','Username')}
      {this.renderInput('email','Email','email')}
      {this.renderSelect('role','Role',this.state.roles)}
      {this.renderInput('password','Password','password')}
      {this.renderButton('Save')}
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

**View:**
[image]

Comment: please show `handleChange`

Comment: I added it, take a look, please.

Comment: i think the cause is `value={data[name]} ` but need to test... it is forcing the value of the select to always be `data[name]`

Comment: So! what should I change there?

Comment: you can trace it through! the `renderInput` method, the third parameter controls the `value` on the `Select` component, and since it's a static value, it will never change 

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar please say what should I change here?

Comment: @ZiaYamin could you please verify whether or not you get the right values when you console.log `data` right before `setState` in `handleChange`?

Comment: @rexessilfie when id ``console.log(data)`` it brings this data ``email: "ziayamin8@gmail.com"
name: "zia"
password: "fadfadf"
role: ""
username: "yamin"``

Comment: That must mean that the role is never set appropriately. I would backtrack and add console.logs to make sure the right values are getting drilled down as expected.

Comment: Could you confirm what values `this.state.roles` contains? Per your code, it should be a list of objects, each with `id` and `name` keys inside of it. Also, try changing `currentTarget` to `target` inside of `handleChange` function parameter.

Comment: @rexessilfie I added a picture to my question, please take a look.

Comment: I changed ``currentTarget`` to ``target``, but the problem is still exists.

Comment: Thanks for the update @ZiaYamin , though I am unable to see what the problem here is unfortunately.